# Ignoring multiple files on pylint 1.4

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint docs states that the `--ignore` flag can be used multiple times. However when running pylint with the following args:

```
pylint --ignore=migrations --ignore=south_migrations
```

Only `south_migrations` is being ignored.

Is there a way to ignore multiple files / directories in pylint 1.4?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is indeed wrong, however there is a workaround:

```
pylint --ignore=migrations,south_migrations
```

Comment: I've created an issue for this pb, see https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/405/bad-documentation-for-ignore-option